# Is it possible to proof |a-b+b - a| <= ulp(a) for all double floating-point numbers?

Tags: floating-point, rounding, precision, numeric

So I want to know, if |a|>=|b|, the inequality |a-b+b-a|<=ulp(a) is true or not, If true, how can I proof the inequality? (the evaluation order is left to right, i.e., ((a-b)+b)-a )

I want to proof, image the a, b are two end points of a line, then if I know the value b and a-b, I want to proof that I can get the value of **a** without error larger than one ULP(a) error. So I can give the condition |a|>=|b| or |a|<=|b|, but I can not limit their actual value.

Comment: It might be a good idea to specify the evaluation order for evaluating a+b+b-a. Presumably you assume those operations to be applied in text order, that is, left to right?

Comment: Is the arithmetic performed according to IEEE-754, is the floating-point radix binary, and is the rounding round-to-nearest-ties-to-even?

Comment: The proposition is false if infinities or NaNs are involved, either directly in the operands or during arithmetic. In particular, if *a* and *b* are near the maximum representable finite value but of opposite signs, then `a-b` is an infinity, and so is `a-b+b-a`, so its magnitude is greater than an ULP of *a*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some preliminaries:

- I assume IEEE-754 arithmetic is used, with a binary radix and round-to-nearest-ties-to-even.
- I further assume that all operands and operation results are finite (neither infinities nor NaNs). (If infinities or NaNs may occur, the proposition is false. If the magnitudes of *a* and *b* are slightly less than the largest representable finite value but they are of opposite signs, then `a−b` is an infinity, so `a−b+b−a` is an infinity, and its magnitude exceeds an ULP of *a*.)
- Italic denotes mathematical variables, such as *a* and *b*. Code format denotes computed arithmetic, such as `a+b`, whereas *a*+*b* is the exact mathematical result.
- I assume *a* and *b* are representable, meaning we are starting with *a* equal to `a` and *b* equal to `b`, not starting with arbitrary real numbers *a* and *b* that are first converted to representable values `a` and `b`.
- The greatest error in round-to-nearest-ties-to-even is ½ ULP of the mathematical result. This is true because any result lies on a representable value or between two representable values. If it is between two values, round-to-nearest chooses the nearer one, the distance to which is at most half the distance between the two.
- For “ULP of *x*”, I will write ULP(*x*). If *x* is not a representable value, ULP(*x*) is the ULP of the greatest representable value less than |*x*|.

|*a*−*b*| is at most 2|*a*|, since |*b*| ≤ |*a*|. So the error in `a−b` is at most ½ ULP(2|*a*|), which is 1 ULP(*a*). Thus `a−b` = *a*−*b*+*e* for some rounding error *e* with |*e*| ≤ ULP(*a*).

Now consider the mathematical result of adding `a−b` and `b`. The mathematical result is `a−b` + *b* = *a*−*b*+*e* + *b* = *a*+*e*. So the mathematical result is within 1 ULP of *a*, inclusive. What then can it round to?

By definition of ULP, the next representable number greater in magnitude than *a* is *a* + ULP(*a*).<sup>1</sup> The next representable number lesser in magnitude is most often *a* − ULP(*a*), but it might be *a* − ½ ULP(*a*) if *a* is exactly a power of two (so it is the lowest number in a binade, and the next lower number has a smaller exponent). Even in this case, there is also another representable number at *a* − ULP(*a*).

Thus the mathematical result, *a*+*e*, lies in the closed interval [*a*−ULP(*a*), *a*+ULP(*a*)], which is bounded by two representable numbers. Let *x* be whichever endpoint is closer to *a*+*e*, and suppose that *a*+*e* rounds to *y* according to the round-to-nearest-ties-to-even rule. If *y* is outside the interval, then the distance from *a*+*e* to *y* is greater than the distance to *x*, either because *y* is beyond *x* in the same direction or because *y* lies in the other direction and hence is beyond the other endpoint, which is at least as far from *a*+*e* as *x* is, so *y* is farther. Therefore, *a*+*e* rounds to one of the endpoints or to some other representable number inside the interval. So it rounds to some number within one ULP of *a*, inclusive.

Thus `a−b+b` is at most 1 ULP(*a*) away from *a*.

## Footnote

<sup>1</sup> For purposes of rounding, if *x* is the largest representable finite value, *x* + ULP(*x*) is treated as representable until the rounding decision is complete. If rounding results in *x* + ULP(*x*) being selected, the result is ∞. (And the same us true symmetrically for negative values.)

Comment: Good discussion.  Some clarification:   Was "is at most ½ ULP of 2| _a_ |" meant to be "is at most ½ ULP of 2|`a`|"?  I'd expect ULP of an exact mathematical _a_ result to be 0 as it has no last place.  Or are you using  ULP(_a_) to be ULP(rounded_to_nearest_double(_a_))  - which has some ambiguity with _a_ in the range (nextafter(some_power_of_2, 0) ... some_power_of_2)?

Comment: @chux: I was using *a* and *b* as the values of `a` and `b`, so 2| *a* | and 2|`a`| are identical. It is only when we start computations that the math and the computation differ, such as in *a* − *b* and `a-b`.

Comment: Sorry if my comment was not clear.  Answer still sounds like ULP is applied to mathematical computation as with "`a-b` is within 1 ULP of _a−b_".  Perhaps "_a-b_ is within 1 ULP of `a−b`"?   Good answer IAC.

Comment: @chux: I was still not clear on what you meant, but I wanted to make the answer more formal anyway, so I did that. Hopefully I clarified things.